# Worksheet Object In Array Automatically Cleared?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Well, I've come across a strange error and I'm not sure why it is happening.  Let me break down how this program works.  So for this program I stuff an array full of different things.  The first element `Array_WS(0)` is a worksheet object, the next, `Array_WS(1)` is the title row number of the worksheet, etc.. When I pass `Array_WS` to another procedure, everything is fine.  However, when I enter a With statement, `With Array_WS(0)` clears the element out...yup you heard right.  When I step through the code, right before `With Array_WS(0)` Sheet1 is assigned...and then immediately upon entering the With statement, bam, `Array_WS(0)` is empty. The below examples should make this a little clearer.

This is how the code looks:

**The Problem**

```
Sub WTF(Array_WS as Variant)
Dim greatValue%

With Array_WS(0)
   greatValue = .Cells(1,1).Value2 <= this works even though Array_WS(0) is now empty
End With

greatValue = Array_WS(0).Cells(1,1).Value2 <= outside the With statement throws an exception
```

**The Fix**

The workaround that I came up with is just this

```
Sub WTF(Array_WS as Variant)
Dim greatValue%, WS as Worksheet

Set WS = Array_WS(0)

With WS
   greatValue = .Cells(1,1).Value2 <= this works
End With

greatValue = Array_WS(0).Cells(1,1).Value2 <= this also works
```

**The Question**

While I have discovered a workaround, I just want to know, **why is this happening??**.  Am I missing something about how objects in arrays which are being passed around work?  Or maybe is there something with With statements that I'm not getting?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
Justin

Comment: You are abusing arrays and variants. They are not meant to contain data of two different types - I suspect something weird is happening because you have an array of different types (at least the intent is to have them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even passing a single object as a Variant array can create problems.  The following will die on the third MsgBox:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim ary(1 To 1) As Variant
    Set ary(1) = ActiveSheet
    Call routine(ary)
End Sub

Sub routine(v As Variant)
    MsgBox v(1).Name
    With v(1)
        MsgBox .Name
    End With
    MsgBox v(1).Name
End Sub
```

but this will not die:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim ary(1 To 1) As Worksheet
    Set ary(1) = ActiveSheet
    Call routine(ary)
End Sub

Sub routine(v As Variant)
    MsgBox v(1).Name
    With v(1)
        MsgBox .Name
    End With
    MsgBox v(1).Name
End Sub
```